# Should mclapply calls be nested?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

Is nesting `parallel::mclapply` calls a good idea?

```
require(parallel)
ans <- mclapply(1:3, function(x) mclapply(1:3, function(y) y * x))
unlist(ans)
```

Outputs:

`[1] 1 2 3 2 4 6 3 6 9`

So it's "working". But is it recommended for real compute-intensive tasks that outnumber the number of cores? what is going on when this is executed? Are the multiple forks involved more potentially wasteful? What are the considerations for `mc.cores` and `mc.preschedule`?

**Edit**
Just to clarify the motivation, often it seems natural to parallelize by splitting one dimension (e.g., use different cores to handle data from *n* different years), then within this split comes another natural way to split (e.g., use different cores to calculate each one of *m* different functions). When m times n is smaller than the total number of available cores the above nesting looks sensible, at least on the face of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the following experiment, the *parallel* execution of the test function `testfn()` was faster compared to the *nested parallel* execution:

```
library(parallel)
library(microbenchmark)
testfn <- function(x) rnorm(10000000)

microbenchmark('parallel'= o <- mclapply(1:8, testfn, mc.cores=4),
               'nested'  = o <- mclapply(1:2, function(x) mclapply(1:4, testfn, mc.cores=2), 
                                         mc.cores=2),
               times=10)
Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 parallel 3.727131 3.756445 3.802470 3.815977 3.834144 3.890128    10
   nested 4.355846 4.372996 4.508291 4.453881 4.578837 4.863664    10
```

**Explanation**:
The communication between the R session and four R workers seems to be more efficient than the communication between the R session and two workers which in turn fork and communicate to two other workers each.

**Alternative**:
The package **foreach** can handle nested loops, which is close to nested `mclapply()` calls; see the vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf.

(The optimal setting of the argument `mc.preschedule` depends on the specific problem; see the help page `?mclapply`.)

Comment: The vignette link is broken