# How to write efficient nested functions for parallelization?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I have a dataframe with two grouping variables `class` and `group`. For each class, I have a plotting task per group.
Mostly, I have **2 levels per** `class` and **500 levels per** `group`.

I'm using `parallel` package for parallelization and `mclapply` function for the iteration through `class` and `group` levels.

I'm wondering which is the best way to write my iterations. I think I have two options:

1. Run parallelization for `class` variable.
2. Run parallelization for `group` variable.

My computer has 3 cores working for R session and usually, preserve the 4th core for my Operating System. I was wondering that if perform the parallelization for `class` variable with 2 levels, the 3rd core will never will be used, so I thought that would be more efficient ensuring all 3 cores will be working running the parallelization for `group` variable. I've written some speed tests to be sure which is the best way:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(parallel)

f = function(class, group, A, B) {
  
  mclapply(seq(class), mc.cores = A, function(z) {
    mclapply(seq(group), mc.cores = B, function(c) {
      ifelse(class == 1, 'plotA', 'plotB')
    })
  })
  
}

class = 2
group = 500

microbenchmark(
  up = f(class, group, 3, 1),
  nest = f(class, group, 1, 3),
  times = 50L
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
   up  6.751193  7.897118 10.89985  9.769894 12.26880 26.87811    50
 nest 16.584382 18.999863 25.54437 22.293591 28.60268 63.49878    50
```

Result tells that I should use the parallelization for `class` and not for `group` variable.

The overview would be that I always should write one-core functions and then call it for parallelization. I think this way, my code would be more simple or reductionist, than write nested functions with parallelization capabilities.

The `ifelse` condition is used because the previous code used to prepare the data for plotting task is more or less redundant for both `class` levels, so I thought it would be more line-coding efficient write a longer function checking which `class` level is used than "splitting" this function in two shorter functions.

Which is the best practice to write this kind of code?. I seams clear, but because I'm not an expert data-scientist, I would like to know your working approach.

[This threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707443/should-mclapply-calls-be-nested) is around this problem. But I think that my question is for both points of view:

- Code beauty and clear
- Speed performance

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked this a while ago but I'll attempt an answer in case anyone else was wondering the same thing. First, I like to split up my task first and then loop over each part. This gives me more control over the process.

```
parts <- split(df, c(df$class, df$group))
mclapply(parts, some_function)
```

Second, distributing tasks to multiple cores takes a lot of computational overhead and can cancel out any gains your make from paralleizing your script. Here, `mclapply` splits the job into however many nodes you have and performs the fork once. This is much more efficient than nesting two `mclapply` loops.