# How to combine jobs to avoid nested lapply

Tags: r, nested, lapply, purrr

I have a data frame where I would like to perform multiple operations with. Here I give you an example to illustrate it, for example to create a list of plots:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_fun = function(data, geom) {

  plot = ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(0), y = Sepal.Length))

  if (geom == 'bar') {
    plot = plot + geom_col()
  } else if (geom == 'box') {
    plot = plot + geom_boxplot()
  }

  plot +
    labs(x = unique(data$Species)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

}
```

As you can see, this function takes a data frame, and perform two types of plots depending the *geom* parameter.

In my real problem, I have to split the data frame by one or multiple factors, and do the job. Do not take care about this specific example (I know I can put iris$Species on x-axis)

```
iris_ls = split(iris, iris$Species)
geom_ls = c('bar', 'box')

lapply(geom_ls, function(g) {
  lapply(iris_ls, function(x) {
    plot_fun(x, g)
  })
})
```

My problem is due if I want to create both types of plots, I have to write a nested lapply (bad performance for parallelization cases).

So my question is, how should I avoid nested lapply procedure?
Should I multiplicate length of *iris_ls* by the length of *geom_ls* vector?
I do not know how to asses this. Imagine I have multiple *geom* like parameters in my function.

PS: Using *drop = TRUE* on *split* function, does not drop factor levels for each element of the list, I don't not know if it's the correct way to do it. I have to use another lapply to do it

Comment: If you want to create both plots for each data.frame, why not adapt your function so that it creates both plots by default? Then you would only need 1 `lapply` call.

Comment: I know I coud use %in% replacing ==, and add result(list(plot_bar, plot_box), but in my real example, it's so much complicated (not plotting related in all cases) and it's not possible. I'm takintg a look to utils::combn to combine all possible combinations of dataframe with geom like parameters....

Comment: You can simply add `data <- droplevels(data)` inside `plot_fun` can't you?  Why do you think nested `lapply` will slow you down?  Unless your lists are very long most of your processing time will be in plotting won't it?

Comment: Thanks Chuck P, but it's related about another question I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581419/how-to-write-efficient-nested-functions-for-parallelization. About drop argument, yes, it's the correct way to do it, sorry, another lapply it's not necessary, but I do not know the purpose of that argument in split function then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the purrr package :

```
cross_ls  <- purrr::cross(list(iris = split(iris, iris$Species),
                               geom = list('bar', 'box')))

cross_ls %>% purrr::map(~{plot_fun(.x$iris,.x$geom)})
```

or in its parallel version :

```
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess)

cross_ls %>% furrr::future_map(~{plot_fun(.x$iris,.x$geom)})
```

Comment: That's it, it performs all combinations and use the custom function. Awesome, thanks

Comment: And how do you parallelize it? Using lapply method, I load 'parallel' package and use mclapply